# Draw an arrow on HTML5 Canvas between two objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on concept maps application, which has a set of nodes and links. I have connected the links to nodes using the center of the node as reference. Since I have nodes with different size and shapes, it is not advisable to draw arrow-head for the link by specifying height or width of the shape. My approach is to draw a link, starting from one node, pixel by pixel till the next node is reached(here the nodes are of different color from that of the background), then by accessing the pixel value, I want to be able to decide the point of intersection of link and the node, which is actually the co-ordinate for drawing the arrow-head.

It would be great, if I could get some help with this.

Sample Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/9tUQP/4/

Here the green squares are nodes and the line starting from left square and entering into the right square is the link. I want the arrow-head to be drawn at the point of intersection of link and the right square.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've created an example that does this. I use [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#Simplification) to walk the line of whole canvas pixels and check the alpha at each point; whenever it crosses a 'threshold' point I record that as a candidate. I then use the first and last such points to draw an arrow (with properly-rotated arrowhead).

Here's the example: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_shape_edge_arrows.html

Refresh the example to see a new random test case. It 'fails' if you have another 'shape' already overlapping one of the end points. One way to solve this would be to draw your shapes first to a blank canvas and then copy the result (`drawImage`) to the final canvas.

For Stack Overflow posterity (in case my site is down) here's the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML5 Canvas Shape Edge Detection (for Arrow)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background:#eee; margin:2em 4em; text-align:center; }
    canvas { background:#fff; border:1px solid #666 }
  </style>
</head><body>
  <canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

    for (var i=0;i<20;++i) randomCircle(ctx,'#999');

    var start = randomDiamond(ctx,'#060');
    var end   = randomDiamond(ctx,'#600');
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = '#099';
    arrow(ctx,start,end,10);

    function arrow(ctx,p1,p2,size){
      ctx.save();

      var points = edges(ctx,p1,p2);
      if (points.length < 2) return 
      p1 = points[0], p2=points[points.length-1];

      // Rotate the context to point along the path
      var dx = p2.x-p1.x, dy=p2.y-p1.y, len=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
      ctx.translate(p2.x,p2.y);
      ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(dy,dx));

      // line
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0,0);
      ctx.lineTo(-len,0);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();

      // arrowhead
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0,0);
      ctx.lineTo(-size,-size);
      ctx.lineTo(-size, size);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.restore();
    }

    // Find all transparent/opaque transitions between two points
    // Uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm
    function edges(ctx,p1,p2,cutoff){
      if (!cutoff) cutoff = 220; // alpha threshold
      var dx = Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x), dy = Math.abs(p2.y - p1.y),
          sx = p2.x > p1.x ? 1 : -1,  sy = p2.y > p1.y ? 1 : -1;
      var x0 = Math.min(p1.x,p2.x), y0=Math.min(p1.y,p2.y);
      var pixels = ctx.getImageData(x0,y0,dx+1,dy+1).data;
      var hits=[], over=null;
      for (x=p1.x,y=p1.y,e=dx-dy; x!=p2.x||y!=p2.y;){
        var alpha = pixels[((y-y0)*(dx+1)+x-x0)*4 + 3];
        if (over!=null && (over ? alpha<cutoff : alpha>=cutoff)){
          hits.push({x:x,y:y});
        }
        var e2 = 2*e;
        if (e2 > -dy){ e-=dy; x+=sx }
        if (e2 <  dx){ e+=dx; y+=sy  }
        over = alpha>=cutoff;
      }
      return hits;
    }

    function randomDiamond(ctx,color){
      var x = Math.round(Math.random()*(ctx.canvas.width  - 100) + 50),
          y = Math.round(Math.random()*(ctx.canvas.height - 100) + 50);
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.translate(x,y);
      ctx.rotate(Math.random() * Math.PI);
      var scale = Math.random()*0.8 + 0.4;
      ctx.scale(scale,scale);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5/scale;
      ctx.fillRect(-50,-50,100,100);
      ctx.strokeRect(-50,-50,100,100);
      ctx.restore();
      return {x:x,y:y};
    }

    function randomCircle(ctx,color){
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(
        Math.round(Math.random()*(ctx.canvas.width  - 100) + 50),
        Math.round(Math.random()*(ctx.canvas.height - 100) + 50),
        Math.random()*20 + 10,
        0, Math.PI * 2, false
      );
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }

  </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: link to my work: http://jsfiddle.net/emYhJ/
Can you pls refactor it to fit my code.

Comment: Thanks anyway.. Figured it out :)

Comment: @allwyn.menezes why do you want to draw it through the 2nd cube? Can you update your fiddle?

Comment: @Phrogz HI there, I tried this method on a white canvas with solid green rectangles. I passed the origin (top left + 5, where rectangles are draw) points of these rectangles to the arrow function but did not get any hits back. Maybe its different points I need to send? maybe I should start a new question..

Comment: var p = new Point(boo.position.x + 5,boo.position.y + 5); var p2 = new Point(foo.position.x + 10,foo.position.y + 10); this.arrow(self.context2D,p, p2);

Comment: I'm also not sure what the **e=dx -dy** var is for? :)

Comment: @FutuToad Yes, you should ask a new question, and then delete these comments.

Comment: @Phrogz ok :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394358/arrows-not-drawing-between-green-rectangles-in-canvas

Comment: @Phrogz I like your application of Bresenham's Algorithm! I have a question: why aren't you using `isPointInPath()`, it seems much more reliable to actually check the path and not the image's alpha channel?